# Two elements on one line using div tags?

Tags: asp.net, html

[image]

Eventually, our team would like to move away from tables, but it seems like div tags are so much harder to use.  In the above image, the layout was created using a table, but I cant figure out how to get a basic column structure working using div tags.  How can I get those buttons on the same line?  HTML newbie here.

Comment: http://www.google.co.uk/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=css+forms

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not too difficult:

**HTML:**

```
<form id="login">
    <div>
        <label for="user">Username:</label>
        <input id="user" type="text" size="20">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="pass">Password:</label>
        <input id="pass" type="password" size="20">
    </div>
    <div>
        <input id="cancel" type="reset" value="Cancel">
        <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Login">
    </div>
</form>
```

**CSS:**

```
#login {
    background-color: #FEFEDD;
    border: 3px solid #7F7F7F;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: right;
}
#login div {
    padding: 5px;
}
#login label {
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
#login #cancel {
    float: left;
}
```

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/URE5b/)**

Comment: So how would you hook up the CSS to the html in this example?

Comment: you could throw it in an external `.css` file and add the proper `<link>` element to your `<head>`, or wrap the CSS with `<style type="text/css">[style here]</style>` and put that into the `<head>` element.

Comment: Sorry to be a pest, but once I add the proper link to my form, will it just automatically do stuff?  Or do I have to do something else?

Answer (score 6):

To be short, if you want to put many elements with div tags in the same line you should give for each div a left float and a width. For example:

```
<div style="width:50px; float:left;"> Element 1</div>
<div style="width:50px; float:left;"> Element 2</div>
...
```

Answer (score 2):

As bad as it is to use tables for positioning elements on a page, forms is one exception I often make.  Sure you can [float](http://www.wipeout44.com/brain_food/css_staying_afloat.asp) your DIVs, but you're going to write a lot more code to do that than using tables.  Plus we're talking about a **tabular** format with rows and columns.  If you're not supposed to use tables for a tabular format, then why have the tags in the HTML at all?

Answer (score 1):

If you give the elements a position:absolute then you can set the left: value and the top:value to align the buttons.

```
div#cancelbutton {
position: absolute;
top:50px;
left:30px;
}
div#loginbutton {
position:absolute;
top:50px;
left:300px;
}
```

This will place the element *quote*: relative to the first parent element that has a position other than static.
Check out http://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_positioning.asp

Comment: Thank you for the sample, but why the div# right before the name?

Comment: I find it useful to give ID's to all my divs. div#cancelbutton is the selector for <div id='cancelbutton'> and div#loginbutton will select <div id='cancelbutton'>. Of course you can also use buttons instead of divs (maybe better in this case). Giving id's to all your divs buttons and inputs just makes it so much easier to keep a nice overall view.

Answer (score 0):

Maybee is better to use float:let then display: inline-block; because IE9 could display textboxes in two rows.
Check http://interestingwebs.blogspot.com/2012/10/div-side-by-side-in-one-line.html for examples.